# How to access dropzone preview elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js to upload images to the server. I have made a custom preview template using "previewTemplate" . I have added 2 input text and 1 textarea with the image.

Now I have to set id,name etc. parameters to the input text and textarea of respected image in on addedFile event, but the problem is that i am unable access the elements using jquery.

when i use file.previewElement to access the elements it returns the complete html code not the reference and hence i am not able to do what i want.

i want to know that how to extract the child div reference from html code it returned.

[image: This is the preview of what it returns]

any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

We can use a querySelector to select any particular tag in document.here is the code what i have done.

```js
_ref = file.previewTemplate.querySelector('[data-tagline]');
_ref.value = file.name;
```

```html
<input type="text" style="margin-top:14px;width:240px;" placeholder="फोटो की टेग लाईन लिखें" data-tagline="" class="lang_class img_description" name="imagetag_Chrysanthemum.jpg" id="imagetag_Chrysanthemum.jpg">
```